# Trying to update VPN profile from IpInterfaceMetric=0 to IpInterfaceMetric=9 in Rasphone.pbk

Tags: powershell, vpn

I am trying to update our VPN profiles AOVPN Device tunnel and User tunnel. I want to update the IpinterfaceMetric from 0 to 9.

What I want to do is to check if script can find the VPN profile first> if not to stop the script>if it can then proceed to the next step to check if it can find 'IpInterfaceMetric=0' word inside the VPN profile. If finds 'IpInterfaceMetric=0'then replace it to 'IpInterfaceMetric=9' but if it did not find 'IpInterfacemetric=0' then to add 'IpInterfaceMetric=9'in that VPN profile.

Also, can we do it in the same script for both VPN profiles.

I am just trying to learn atm and any ideas will be appreciated. Below is just the scratch script that I have wrote.

```
    try { 
    Get-VpnConnection -Name $VPNprofile -ErrorAction Stop
    }
catch 
    { Add-VpnConnection -Name $VPNprofile -ServerAddress $serverIp -AuthenticationMethod MSChapv2 -DnsSuffix local -EncryptionLevel Required -PassThru -RememberCredential -SplitTunneling -TunnelType L2tp -UseWinlogonCredential
    }
finally
    { 
      $username = $((gwmi win32_Computersystem -Property UserName -Impersonation Impersonate).Username).Split("\")[1] 
    $rasphone = ('C:\Users\' + $username + '\Appdata\Roaming\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\rasphone.pbk'
        
    $xc = 'IpInterfaceMetric=0'
    $checkWord = Get-Content $rasphone | %{$_ -match $xc}

    if ($checkWord -contains $true){
       (Get-Content $rasphone) -replace $xc, 'IpInterfaceMetric=9'| Set-Content $rasphone
       }

     else { 
       Add-Content $rasphone -value "IpInterfaceMetric=9"| Set-Content $rasphone
     } 
     }
```